# Is there a way to show all variations beside each other (not dropdown)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show my product variations (from WooCommerce) beside each other, kinda like buttons but still options:

---

Buy format:
Hire            Buy

---

Instead of a drop down.

This is because I want the customer to have the power to compare the two options (and the options related to the option) easy. Like this:

---

Buy format:
Hire            **Buy**

Subscription:
Unbinding (399 SEK/month)         Binding (299 SEK/month)

---

and

---

Buy format:
**Hire**           Buy

Subscription:
Unbinding (595 SEK/month)         Binding (495 SEK/month)

---

So, is there anyway to accomplish this? Can I see the code for the variations somewhere?

I have tried using different plugins, but I couldn't achieve the desired solution without perhaps buying something. Right now, I am trying to figure out if I can change the code through a child template but my knowledge of PHP doesn't take me far unfortunately.

Right now, the variations are shown through drop downs. I want to show them beside each other, kinda like buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use the follows filter to do the above -

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', $html, $args )
```

Comment: Where should I use this filter? I'm so sorry to bother you with such a basic question, but I'm fairly new to WordPress and try to understand the ins and outs :)